# Правильное написание "Директор генеральный" или "Генеральный директор"

Tags: стилистика

Здравствуйте. В канцелярии отказались принять сл. записку с обращением, КОМУ: "Директору генеральному", просят исправить на Генеральному директору". Есть ли какой-то регламент в написании должности?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно просят. Должность называется Генеральный директор, так и пишите, зачем искажать? И вообще, в русском языке при прямом (обычном) порядке слов согласованное определение находятся перед главным словом, инверсия в деловом стиле неуместна.